# Rounding issue with SQL Server and REAL datatype

Tags: sql-server, rounding

I'm seeing some strange behavior when rounding in SQL Server 2008. Given the following code:

```
DECLARE @Value REAL
SELECT @Value = .35
SELECT ROUND(@Value, 1)
```

I would expect the value to be .4, however it outputs .3. I must assume this is because the value stored is actually less than .35, something like .34999999999999. Is this the case, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to ensure this behaves as expected, at least from the visible value?

Comment: What do you get if `@Value` is of type `DECIMAL(10,2)`? Remember that `REAL` is an approximate data type, meaning it may indeed store .35 as .34999999999999 or something similar.

Comment: Using a DECIMAL(10,2) gives the expected result. Unfortunately, my database is already using REAL for this. Maybe I need to look at converting.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest converting. `REAL` and `FLOAT` are not the data type you should use if you expect logical (e.g. more approximate than what most of science teaches you) rounding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are using floating-point values like REAL and FLOAT (same thing), the SQL Server ROUND() function follows IEEE Standard 754 and uses the "round up" algorithm.

But that means different things for different floating-point values. Some ".5" values end up getting stored as an approximation of ".49999999999", others as ".500000001", etc. It rounds up the value that is actually stored, not the value you gave it to begin with.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx

If exact decimal math matters to you, use DECIMAL, not FLOAT or REAL.

Answer (score 8):

It's too bad the data is stored as REAL, but not all hope is lost. Convert the REAL to DECIMAL(10,2) before rounding it. That way the 0.3499999999999 (or whatever inaccurate value is being stored) will be rounded to .35, and then you'll round that to 0.4. You can even convert he result to DECIMAL(10,1) if you want it to be displayed as `0.4`:

```
DECLARE @Value REAL
SELECT @Value = .35
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @Value), 1))
```

Comment: This apparently works! Kudos! I wonder how fast these conversions are. If I just replace the round with this calculation, I wonder how much it'll hurt me.