# SQL Server rounding differently based on data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why does rounding in SQL Server behave non-intuitively?

```
SELECT CAST(     19.845           AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [DecOK]
      ,CAST(CAST(19.845 AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [DecBad]
      ,CAST(19.845 AS FLOAT)          AS [Float]
      ,CAST(19.845 AS FLOAT) - 19.845 AS [NoDiff]
      ,ROUND(     19.845          , 2) AS [RoundOK]
      ,ROUND(CAST(19.845 AS FLOAT), 2) AS [RoundBad]
```

Actual:

```
DecOK   DecBad  Float   NoDiff  RoundOK RoundBad
19.85   19.84   19.845  0       19.850  19.84
```

Expected:

```
DecOK   DecBad  Float   NoDiff  RoundOK RoundBad
19.85   19.85   19.845  0       19.850  19.85
```

I would expect the value to be the same, regardless of the data type. How can I guarantee accurate results when working with FLOATs? Is the `NoDiff` value implicitly converting the second value to a FLOAT which is why the result is exactly 0?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526386/rounding-issue-with-sql-server-and-real-datatype

Comment: *How can I guarantee accurate results when working with FLOATs* Answer is **Big No**. In MSDN it is clearly stated that "*Float is Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly*"

Answer (score 0):

Float is an approximate precision.  If you want precision, use DECIMAL or NUMERIC which are the same thing.

There are a lot of posts on this but here is a great one.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158770

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm working with an existing table created over a year ago. I'm multiplying two numbers, one with 2 decimal places, one with 3 decimal places, but stored as a FLOAT. Now I'm converting the result to DECIMAL(18, 5) before converting it to DECIMAL(18, 2) and the rounding is correct.